# My graphic file is not showing on the PDF, nor is the succeeding text, why is this?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I have been trying to present my work via LaTeX, I am pretty much a beginner. I have used the following code thus far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}


\title{ECM2709 Continuous Assessment}
\author{H. Millard}
\date{October 12, 2015}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Question 1}
\subsection{1(a)}

The simplest way to compare the distributions of the forecast and recorded data is to plot a histogram of each variable against each other and visually compare the two (see Figure 1).

\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{hist1}
     \caption{A histogram of the forecast and the observed wind speeds across all years}
\end{figure}

Purely from visual observation we can make certain assumptions. Firstly, an obvious similarity is the spread of data. For both sets, the minimum value is between 0 and 1 and the maximum falls between 17 and 19.

\end{document}
```

The file hist1 is a .PNG file, which is saved within the same folder as the .tex file. I compile the code using the PDFLaTeX option on TeXMaker.

There are no LaTeX errors thrown, although I do get a 'no \author given' warning for Line 1 which is strange as there is clearly an author.

The PDF file comprises of the title, without the author, and the first block of text, but no image or caption, and no 2nd block of text after the figure.

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.21) 2 NOV 2015 16:14
entering extended mode
**CW.tex
(U:\ecm2709\coursework\CW.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans,      ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(U:\ecm2709\coursework\CW.aux)
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <12> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <8> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 7.
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.
[1
{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(U:\ecm2709\coursework\CW.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
230 strings out of 493921
2498 string characters out of 3146456
50031 words of memory out of 3000000
3599 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
7587 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
23i,6n,17p,175b,193s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17
.pfb>
Output written on CW.pdf (1 page, 46843 bytes).
PDF statistics:
22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

If you need any specific images or code please ask and advise on how to present them, I am new here.

Comment: `[H]` is not a valid option for `figure` without the `float` package. although it should have given you an error. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: it gives the same output, still throwing the 'no \author given' warning, I can only assume this must be part of the problem

Comment: your example here doesn't have a `\end{document}` at the end. is that the same on your file? if so you should add it.

Comment: I have put it in now, there was one in the original file yes.

Comment: Add the `[demo]` option for `graphicx` and see if that works (it will use a black blob in place of your image). If it doesn't, post the complete `.log` file you get, while if it does then there is something about your image that's problematic.

Comment: temporarily comment out the `float` package and see it that changes anything.  if the missing material appears, that could indicate that the `float` package has been corrupted.

Comment: according to the LOG file, it stops at line 7 (where the \author is) and throws the 'no \author given' warning, there is no log notes for lines after this

Comment: I have put the complete .log file in the new edit

Comment: This can't be the log-file of the document above. Are you sure that you are compiling the correct file? Perhaps you did set another file as main file.

Comment: I promise you they are the same file.

Comment: I didn't have an author before, then I put one in to try and get rid of the warning and it still has the same warning, is there any possible explanation for this??

Comment: I have no problem whatsoever to compile your file. Perhaps, delete the auxiliary files before recompiling.

Comment: Concur with @Bernard.  It compiles without error when the png file actually exists and is not corrupted.   Also I have a recently (3 weeks ago) updated installation of MikTeX.

Comment: I have just done this, and it still says 'no \author given', this is frustrating!

Comment: Is the graphics file in the same directory as the .tex file?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the same folder

Comment: Effectively, everytime I compile it just has the same log file and the same output regardless of me changing the code

Comment: The `.log` file does not belong to the file posted as source. The `.log` says, that its source is `U:\ecm2709\coursework\CW.tex`, which does not load any packages.

Comment: So why isn't the log updating now that I have amended the error?

Comment: Try copying the `.tex` file in a new folder, along with the `.png` file and nothing else. Now compile the new copy. What happens?

Comment: Ian, it comes up with 'Log file not found!'

Comment: There have been a few questions about this error. Do any of [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=texmaker%20log%20file%20not%20found%20is%3aquestion) help?

Comment: I close the question as unclear, as the discussion about it stopped 1 month ago, and there's no result.